# Como esconder parte de uma view?

Tags: java, android

Tenho o **StickerBtn.java** com o seguinte código:

```
public class StickerBtn extends View {

    private Bitmap mControllerBitmap

    private void init() {

        mControllerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_refreshing);
        mControllerWidth = mControllerBitmap.getWidth();
        mControllerHeight = mControllerBitmap.getHeight();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (stickers.size() <= 0) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stickers.size(); i++) {
            stickers.get(i).getmMatrix().mapPoints(stickers.get(i).getMapPointsDst(), stickers.get(i).getMapPointsSrc());
            canvas.drawBitmap(stickers.get(i).getBitmap(), stickers.get(i).getmMatrix(), null);
            if (stickers.get(i).isFocusable()) {

                canvas.drawBitmap(mControllerBitmap, stickers.get(i).getMapPointsDst()[4] - mControllerWidth / 2, stickers.get(i).getMapPointsDst()[5] - mControllerHeight / 2, null);

                canvas.drawBitmap(mDeleteBitmap, stickers.get(i).getMapPointsDst()[0] - mDeleteWidth / 2, stickers.get(i).getMapPointsDst()[1] - mDeleteHeight / 2, null);

            }
        }

    }
```

E tenho o **MainActivity.java** com o seguinte:

```
imgSave = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgSave);
imgSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
...
}
```

O que tenho que colocar no lugar dos **três pontos** para quando o usuário pressionar a imagem save ele esconda ou remova o **R.drawable.ic_refreshing**?

Já tentei o seguinte, mas da erro, pois está em outra classe:

```
mControllerBitmap.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tenta mControllerBitmap.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Comment: Você quer esconder a imagem do botão mas mantendo o botão? O que quer dizer com "save ele"?

Comment: Eu quero que ao pressionar a imagem "R.id.imgSave" ele remova o "R.drawable.ic_refreshing" da tela. Quando tento o setvisibility, ele diz o seguinte: Cannot resolve symbol 'mControllerBitmap'.

Comment: O R.drawable.ic_refreshing é usado dentro de StickerBtn. Onde/como você usa o StickerBtn? Está mais difícil  perceber o que quer do que eventualmente resolver o problema.

Comment: Qual código tenho que utilizar no mainactivity para manipular o ícone que está na pasta drawable do projeto e é utilizado em outra classe.

Comment: Só isso não é suficiente, existem várias possibilidades. Onde/como você usa o StickerBtn? Quer apenas esconder o R.drawable.ic_refreshing e manter a view StickerBtn?

Comment: StickerBtn é criado para ficar ao lado de uma imagem que muda de tamanho quando pressiona o botão R.drawable.ic_refreshing. Quero apenas esconder o R.drawable.ic_refreshing quando a pessoa for salvar essa imagem.

Comment: StickerBtn e R.drawable.ic_refreshing não são a mesma coisa?

Comment: R.drawable.ic_refreshing é um dos botões que compõe o StickerBtn. Quando a pessoa seleciona a imagem que quer editar o StickerBtn cria vários botões em volta da imagem com opções de edição. Um desses botões é o R.drawable.ic_refreshing, que eu quero fazer ele desaparecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione à classe StickerBtn um campo para controlar se o Bitmap é desenhado ou não no método `onDraw()`.

```
private boolean drawControllerBitmap; // inicialize com true caso pretenda 
                                      // que inicialmente seja desenhado.
```

Adicione um *setter* e, eventualmente, um *getter* para esse campo:

```
public void setControllerBitmapVisible(boolean visible){
    drawControllerBitmap = visible;
    invalidate(); //Isto faz com que o método onDraw seja chamado
}

public boolean getControllerBitmapVisible(){
    return drawControllerBitmap;
}
```

No método `onDraw()` apenas desenhe o Bitmap se drawControllerBitmap for verdadeiro.

No "lugar dos três pontos" use `setControllerBitmapVisible(false)`, do objecto instanciado da classe StickerBtn, para remover(não desenhar) o R.drawable.ic_refreshing.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, iniciei o drawControllerBitmap como true, depois controlei a exibição com o setControllerBitmapVisible(). E apenas desenhe o Bitmap se drawControllerBitmap for verdadeiro. Obrigado.